# Can you set the FileFilters for a Gtk Dialog in Glade?

Tags: dialog, gtk, glade

In my code, I have lines like this:

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
builder.AddFromFile(gladefile);
FileChooserDialog dialog =
    (FileChooserDialog) builder.GetObject("dialog");

FileFilter[] filters = new FileFilter[2];
filters[0] = new FileFilter();
filters[0].Name = "Some filter";
filters[0].AddPattern("*.someextension");
filters[1] = new FileFilter();
filters[1].Name = "All files";
filters[1].AddPattern("*");

foreach (FileFilter filter in filters)
    dialog.AddFilter(filter);
dialog.Filter = filters[0];
dialog.SetFilename(defaultFile);
```

Is there a way to set up these filters in Glade, rather than doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can create a file filter object in glade (version 3.6 and up) and add it to the dialog, but since you can't actually set the name or pattern of the file filter, it's fairly useless.

Comment: Oh well, alright. Do you know if there are any plans to allow you to set the name or pattern?

Comment: I don't know, but it's probably not up to Glade. Glade (and GtkBuilder) let you set the properties of GObjects, but the file filter stuff isn't implemented as GObject properties. So I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: You can set the pattern since GTK+ 3.0 (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/commit/031a09225461eb53f44d27d993c46dc9a11e2cc6). The name can be set from the id of the object in the XML, though I am proposing a name property for that (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/merge_requests/376). I have proposed setting the filter list in https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/merge_requests/380.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible now. The code snippet should probably look something like this:

```
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_objects_from_file("***name of glade file****.glade",
        ("filechooserdialog1", "filefilter1"))
    dialog = self.builder.get_object("filechooserdialog1")
    filefilter = self.builder.get_object("filefilter1")
    dialog.add_filter(filefilter)
```

[image]

[image]